# Web application and PC write/read connection

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm working on a web application - optimized for Google Chrome - which needs write access on the client's PC. 
Detailed, it's a Laravel app (but i don't think it's important) which has a button to print fiscal receipt/ticket and the procedure is, that the printer has it's own (windows based) software which runs in resident mode (checking periodically in "C:\tickets\cash.inp" file) - thereby i need somehow to write that file - without prompting the user to save that file.

Possible solutions:

- jQuery and Javascript - not possible
- HTML5 Filesystem API - not possible
- Chrome extension / packaged app - not possible, only writes in LocalStorage (or something like this), not in C:\tickets\
- ActiveX - i think it's only for IE
- Client App - listening a protocol (like MagnetLink) - is this possible?

Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short: no, it's not possible without you writing a browser extension.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. But according to chrome.filesystem the user will be asked / prompted - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons it's impossible to write on the user's disk directly. I think the best way to accomplish something like this with an client-side app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you have already pointed out you need some utility that can do this for you whenever required.

So, either you can create some small `java` based utility or `.NET` to read write the file on user's system and connection to utility using `web-socket` when required.